# Disable UITableView Scrolling during editing

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` configured to NO scrolling. In standard state (not in editing mode) the scrolling is correctly disabled but when i go in editing mode and I think to move row the scrolling is enabled and this cause some problem. Why, if the scrollingEnabled property is set to NO the scrolling is enabled in editing mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

use this code after adding to view (or initilizing `UITableView`)

Answer (score -3):

You need an if statement i.e. `if (self.editing) { UITableView.scrolling = FALSE;}`

Comment: Where would you put that exactly?

Comment: That implies a polling based method. Avoid this.